# ¿Antes de finalizar un pedido en WooCommerce como puedo validar las existencias de los productos del carrito?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

En Woocommerce, antes de que el cliente pague un pedido necesito validar que haya existencia de los productos del carrito conectándome a una BD de un ERP que maneja los mismos productos y tiene servicios web para consultarlas. Esta existencia puede ser diferente a la que tengo en Woocommerce y son las actualizadas. Me ha sucedido que un cliente hace una compra y ya no hay productos en existencia. He intentado con varios Hooks de la página carrito pero no he dado con el correcto.

Inicialmente verifico que el hook utilizado efectivamente es el correcto y muestro algún dato para probarlo, posteriormente haré la conexión con la BD y las comprobaciones del caso. Los hooks con los que he realizado pruebas son: woocommerce_payment_complete y woocommerce_review_order_before_submit. Muchas gracias.

El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete','Captura_despues_de_pago',10); 
function Captura_despues_de_pago( $order_id) { 
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
$items = $order->get_items(); 
echo "Items: " .$items; 
foreach( $items as $item ) { 
    echo $item['product_id']; 
    echo "<br>"; }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Podrias mostrarnos que intentaste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

logré realizar lo que necesitaba. Comparto el código por si alguien lo necesita. El hook que utilicé es

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','Validacion_antes_de_pago',10);
function Validacion_antes_de_pago() {

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
$item = $cart_item['data'];
$SkuaBuscar=$item->sku;
$CantidadWC = (int) $cart_item['quantity'];  //es la cantidad en el pedido de WC
```

... aquí va el codigo de configuración y conexión a la base externa.

```
$items_origin = curl_exec($ch);  //Ejecuto la consulta a la BD y traigo la existencia del producto
curl_close($ch);
$ErrorenCantidad="";

// Obtenemos datos de la API externa y validamos si la existencia es correcta
$ProductosProv=json_decode($items_origin,true);
foreach($ProductosProv as $Produ) {
    $param_existe=(int) $Produ['Quantity'];  //ES la cantidad externa
    if ($param_existe<$CantidadWC ) {
        $ErrorenCantidad.="Lo sentimos, del producto " .$SkuaBuscar . " sólo quedan en existencia " .$param_existe ."<br>";
    }
}
IF ($ErrorenCantidad<>"") {
    wp_redirect(wc_get_page_permalink('cart'));
    exit;
}
}
```

Ahora estoy intentando mostrar un mensaje en la página del carrito donde muestre los productos cuya existencia es menor a lo solicitado en el pedido, es decir, la variable $ErrorenCantidad pero nada que lo logro, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Aún tienes inconvenientes para resolver el script ? Estoy desarrollando lo mismo, y tengo una parte del codigo que te haría falta, contactame al correo silvio.sotelo@century.com.py